# Gyroscope dps conversion

Tags: data, imu, gyroscope

I am doing a data collection using an Axivity AX6 IMU equipped with an accelerometer and gyroscope (BMI160). I am using the OMGUI software to start the collection where I can choose between different gyroscope range options such as 250, 500, 1000, 2000 dps. For the experiments, I am using a dps of 500, however during one collection I mistakenly set to 1000 dps. Is there a possibility of converting values obtained at 1000 dps to 500dps?

Below you can find an image showing the data for the Gyroscope:

[image]

Comment: This question needs clarification such as what the IMU's output format is as well as the part number. I assume it's just a scaled binary output and when you say "dps" you just mean the full scale range? However you say "*the gyroscope I am using a dps of 500, however during one collection it is set to 1000 dps*" which seems to imply you have a recording device with settings. Frankly, you have provided far too few details.

Comment: @DKNguyen I just added some more information concerning my issue.

Comment: Is the dps seting in OMGUI the full scale range?

Comment: Are you asking how to multiply or divide the data by a factor of two? Is that it?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Probably

Answer (score 0):

The gyro produces a raw binary format that is then scaled by the dps setting in OMGUI. If OMGUI is set to scale the raw binary output to double the range it should be, it means all the converted readings from the gyro all read half their actual values (since it think each binary count represents half the degrees per second so that double the range can fit into the same full span of binary counts).